# Cambiar nombre de botones DateRangePicker

Tags: php, javascript

Estoy utilizando [Daterangepicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example4)
El problema esque esta en ingles y necesito hacer algunos ajustes a español:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo cambiar el nombre de la opción`CustomRange`y el nombre de los botones `Apply y Cancel`.
Mi codigo actual:

```
var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
var end = moment();

function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange_right span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
}

$('#reportrange_right').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
       'Hoy': [moment(), moment()],
       'Ayer': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
       'Ultimos 7 dias': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
       'Ultimos 30 dias': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
       'Este mes': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
       'Mes pasado': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
}, cb);

cb(start, end);

$('#reportrange_right').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
    //Cuando se selecciona una opcion 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

si te vas a la página puedes ver que hay un menu que dice Configuration Generator
ahi busca la opcion locale seleccionala y 
te sale

```
locale": {
        "format": "MM/DD/YYYY",
        "separator": " - ",
        "applyLabel": "Apply",
        "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
        "fromLabel": "From",
        "toLabel": "To",
        "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
```

cambia Apply y Cancel y Custom por cualquier cosa que quieras 
y agregalo al array de configuracion

Comment: ya cambie eso y sigue igual

Comment: actualiza el codigo que tienes en tu pregunta para ver que es lo que cambiaste por favor

Comment: solo el nombre de _Apply y Cancel_

Comment: pero no lo estoy viendo ponlo aqui para verlo

Comment: yo creo que si funciona: [ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/3gf0eLzh/2/) y es tu código